# How To Make Cross-Origin Requests In Firefox Add-ons?

Tags: firefox, google-chrome-extension, firefox-addon, cors

I have created an extension in Chrome. Now I need to transfer it into a Firefox extension. The extension makes cross origin requests. I am new to developing Firefox add-ons and I've heard about /request API, but it is only available in the main script of the application.

How do I make cross-origin requests from the panel opened with Firefox add-on?

Comment: It sounds like you are trying to do requests from inside the content script. What you want to do is [MDN DOCS - port.emit](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/Guides/Content_Scripts/using_port#port.emit%28%29) that sends message to your main script, it will do the request and send the info back.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've had the same issue when porting a chrome add-on to firefox.

There are effectively 3 kinds of script in a firefox add-on

---

Page-scripts: Loaded in HTML using `<script>` tags

Content-Scripts: Injected from the main.js

AddOn-Scripts: The main.js file.

---

Scripts that are loaded using a `<script>` tag in a html file are insulated from the outside world and thus can't make XHR requests. If you're looking to be able to make an XHR request you'll need to inject the file as a content script.

You can read more on this at the following link: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/Guides/Content_Scripts